# How to delete words of certain language (in my case Chinese) on Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

What I want is that remove all Chinese text from Sheet:

Sample of issue:

[image]

Comment: How have you tried to solve your problem? This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with complex formulas or code you are trying to develop. To learn about this site, start by taking the [2-minute tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the best way to achieve what you want, but you could loop through characters in each cell and if they don't fall within the [A to Z] or [a to z] or [0 to 9] replace the character with a space and then Trim extra spaces.

**EDIT:**

As per cybernetic.nomad's comment, I've also included commas, apostrophes and periods in the ASCII lookup:

```
Sub foo()
Dim i As Long, x As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim StrVal As String
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column I, amend to whichever column you are using

For i = 1 To LastRow 'loop from row 1 to last on Column I
    For x = 1 To Len(ws.Cells(i, "I")) 'loop through characters in each cell
        StrVal = Mid(ws.Cells(i, "I"), x, 1)
        If IsLetter(StrVal) = False Then 'check if character is valid in English
            ws.Cells(i, "I") = Replace(ws.Cells(i, "I"), StrVal, " ") 'if not replace with a space
        End If
    Next x
    ws.Cells(i, "I") = Trim(ws.Cells(i, "I")) 'trim extra spaces from cell
Next i
End Sub

Function IsLetter(strValue As String) As Boolean
'function to check whether character is between [A-Z], [a-z], [0-9], Comma, Apostrophe and Periods.
        Select Case Asc(strValue)
            Case 65 To 90, 97 To 122, 48 To 57, 39, 44 To 46 
                IsLetter = True
            Case Else
                IsLetter = False
        End Select
End Function
```

Comment: You'll also want to add numbers [0-9] and common western typographic characters (I spotted some hyphens in the screen cap provided, but you'll probably also want to keep apostrophes, commas, periods, etc..)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad updated to include numbers, commas, apostrophes and periods.